# Actionscript 2.0 changing color by getting color from another movieclip

Tags: colors, actionscript-2

The question may be a little confusing so I will try to simplify it the best I can

I have 2 movieclips on stage with instance names mc1 & mc2

The code in frame is as follows

```
mc1.onRelease = function() {
    col = new Color(this);
    col.setRGB(Math.random()*"0xFFFFFF");
}
mc2.onRelease = function() {
    orig_col = new Color(mc1);
    new_col = new Color(this);
    new_col.setRGB(orig_col.getRGB()*"0xFFFFFF");
}
```

The mc1 function is working fine(it's color is getting randomized). But when a user clicks mc2, it gets some weird color, not the color of mc1

Basically, I want when we press mc2, it's color will be what mc1's is..

Please help me fix this...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems helpful for the script of mc2 (the script of mc1 is fine)

```
mc2.onRelease = function() {
    orig_col = new Color(mc1);
    new_col = new Color(this);
    full_color = "0x"+orig_col.getRGB().toString(16);
    new_col.setRGB(full_color);
}
```